# Socket io and undefined object in js class

Tags: javascript, oop, socket.io

I have some problem with socket.io and Javascript classes. I can't access an object from my class. It returns *undefined*.

Code of my problem:

```
pong.scenes.Game = function() {
    this.paddle = new pong.entities.Paddle(_size.width/2, _size.height - 74, false);
    this.appendChild(this.paddle);

    this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3015');
    this.socket.on('move', this._onMoveServer);
};

goog.inherits(pong.scenes.Game, pong.scenes.VO.gameSceneVO);

goog.object.extend(pong.scenes.Game.prototype, {
    _onMouseMove: function(e) {
        var pos = this.paddle.getPosition();
        pos.x = e.position.x;
        this.socket.emit('move', { x: pos.x, y: pos.y });
    },
    _onMoveServer: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var pos = null;
        pos = data.x;
        this.paddle.x = pos; <---- ERROR!
        console.log(this.paddle);
    }
});
```

When I want access to object this.paddle i got undefined error. Someone know what's happening?

Comment: It seems that paddle is simply not defined in that scope, you define it in `pong.scenes.Game` but it's not available in `goog`, perhaps you want to do `this.paddle = {}` first and then `this.paddle.x = pos`?

Comment: So I can't access to objects from class? I must define everytime new paddle when I handling message?